# FastAPI rooter returns errors

Tags: python, fastapi, webdav

I want to create a rooter using the get method

My code looks like this

```
from fastapi import FastAPI, Query
@app.get("/connect")
async def files_info(url:str,  username:str, password:str):
    url=test_url
    username="username"
    password="password"
    conn=Connector(url, username, password)
    return json.dumps(conn.get_files_info(""), indent=4, ensure_ascii=False)
```

But it returns

```
{"detail":[{"loc":["query","url"],"msg":"field required","type":"value_error.missing"},{"loc":["query","username"],"msg":"field required","type":"value_error.missing"},{"loc":["query","password"],"msg":"field required","type":"value_error.missing"}]}
```

How I can resolve this problem ?

Comment: What does your URL look like? It should be something like `http://127.0.0.1:8000/connect/?url=something&username=something&password=something`.

Comment: How are you calling your API? Because the error is saying you are missing all the required fields. Have you read: https://fastapi.tiangolo.com/tutorial/query-params/?

Comment: url looks "https://example.com/webdav". Ma root should be "/connect"

Answer (score 0):

I think it's because the url, username, and password parameters are not marked as required, so they will not be considered missing when the function is called, which is why the error message is returned I think.